# What's the latest version of berkeley-db-je?

Tags: berkeley-db, berkeley-db-je

What's the latest version of `berkeley-db-je`?

From [oracle](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/berkeleydb/downloads/index.html), it is 7.5.

But from [maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sleepycat/je) repository, it is 18.3.12.

It there anyone know more details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of Berkeley DB Java Edition is 7.5.11
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/berkeleydb/overview/index-093405.html

The 18.x versions you are seeing in maven are Oracle NoSQL Database Community Edition (CE).

Some info on the database can be found here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/other-databases/nosql-database/19.5/concepts/introduction.html

> Oracle NoSQL Database uses Oracle Berkeley DB Java Edition as its underlying storage engine.